# my project is not running try everything flutter clean upgrade flutter build nothings works

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies

You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\91972\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.7.20\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\91972\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_app_check-0.2.1+18\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\appcheck\FlutterFirebaseAppCheckPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\91972\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.15.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_share:parseReleaseLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_share:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\91972\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\91972\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 31s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The log is literally telling you to head [here](https://flutter.dev/go/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) to solve the problem. Either you check the solution proposed on that page or you create a new project and copy the important files and folders there (lib, pubspec.yaml, ...).